# send messages to friends via facebook api programatically in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, api

I have checked with the facebook docs. I could see only possibility of read not write for messages.

Just to reconfirm -

Is there a way in facebook api to send messages to friends programatically in ruby?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in ANY language. You can use the Send Dialog of the JavaScript SDK, but it is not possible to send messages automatically (for obvious spam reasons): https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

It was only possible with the Chat API earlier, but it´s deprecated now: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/

...meaning, it will only be possible until April 2015, and ONLY with an App created before end of April 2014. Not worth it to implement the Chat API anymore.